# Clique number for hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph

Does anybody know any link/source where I can find examples of hypergraphs with their clique numbers? I need a few examples to test an algorithm and do not want to go for randomly generated hypergraph.
Any help will be appreciated.